# C# - Overloading Templated Method That Has No Arguments

Tags: c#, oop, interface, overloading

Say I have an interface `WorksWithType<T>` and class `MyClass` that implements both `WorksWithType<TypeA>` and `WorksWithType<TypeB>`.

If my interface looks like

```
public interface WorksWithType<T> {
     void DoSomething(T foo);
     void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

it is easy to implement two different `DoSomething` method overloads in `MyClass`.

```
public class MyClass : WorksWithType<TypeA>, WorksWithType<TypeB> {
{
    public void DoSomething(TypeA fooA) { ... } 
    public void DoSomething(TypeB fooB) { ... } 
    ...
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to implement overloads of `DoSomethingElse`. In my mind I feel as though I should be able to change the signature on the interface to be

```
void DoSomethingElse<T>();
```

and then overload the class with

```
public void DoSomethingElse<TypeA>() { ... } 
public void DoSomethingElse<TypeB>() { ... }
```

What is the correct approach here, if there is one?

Comment: In order to achieve this you´ll need the generic parameter on the method, not on the interface.

Comment: @dlatikay: I think they're definitely very closely related, but this one is a better one as it deals with *one* aspect (just the implementation) rather than 1) Why am I getting a warning about type parameter hiding? 2) How do I call the method I want? 3) (Not even clearly stated, partly due to issue 1) How do I implement the interface?

Comment: Please, next type you declare an interface start the name with a capital `I`, as in `IWorksWithType<T>`. It is a universal standard in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the two implementations of `DoSomethingElse` to be different , you need to use [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to distinguish between the calls:

```
public class TypeA {}
public class TypeB {}

public interface IWorksWithType<T>
{
     void DoSomething(T foo);
     void DoSomethingElse();
}

public class MyClass : IWorksWithType<TypeA>, IWorksWithType<TypeB>
{
    public void DoSomething(TypeA fooA) {}
    public void DoSomething(TypeB fooB) {} 

    // Note the syntax here - this indicates which interface
    // method you're implementing        
    void IWorksWithType<TypeA>.DoSomethingElse() {}
    void IWorksWithType<TypeB>.DoSomethingElse() {}
}
```

You don't have to make *both* of them use explicit interface implementation. For example:

```
public class MyClass : IWorksWithType<TypeA>, IWorksWithType<TypeB>
{
    public void DoSomething(TypeA fooA) {}
    public void DoSomething(TypeB fooB) {} 

    // Explicit interface implementation
    void IWorksWithType<TypeA>.DoSomethingElse() {}
    // Implicit interface implementation
    public void DoSomethingElse() {}
}
```

If you don't need the implementations to be different, you can just have three methods of course:

```
public class MyClass : IWorksWithType<TypeA>, IWorksWithType<TypeB>
{
    public void DoSomething(TypeA fooA) {}
    public void DoSomething(TypeB fooB) {}

    // Implementation of both IWorksWithType<TypeA>.DoSomethingElse()
    // and IWorksWithType<TypeB>.DoSomethingElse()
    public void DoSomethingElse() {}
}
```

That's assuming you to want the type parameter to be on the interface. You *could* put it on the method instead, but that really represents a very different interface - and you wouldn't be able to say that `MyClass` can only call `DoSomethingElse` for types `TypeA` and `TypeB`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

By the current C# specifications (draft 6) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction

> The signature of a method must be unique in the class in which the method is declared. The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, **the number of type parameters** and the number, modifiers, and types of its parameters. The signature of a method does not include the return type

(emphasis mine)

So, unfortunately,

```
void MyMethod<TypeA>()
```

and

```
void MyMethod<TypeB>()
```

**would not have different signatures**, so you cannot, per the specs, define both of them : they differ only *by the **type** of their type parameter, but not by the **number** of their type parameter*

Other answers have already pointed out how you could work around this (the explicit interface implementation is a good idiomatic option in my opinion)

Comment: More importantly, `void MyMethod<TypeA>()` would be introducing `TypeA` as a type *parameter*, whereas I believe the OP would want to be effectively using it as a type *argument*. Fundamentally I think they're reaching for syntax to solve a problem, but they've reached for the wrong syntax.

Comment: Yes, maybe I misunderstood a bit OP's goal, but hopefully the specs might shed some light to the confusion.

Comment: My expectation is that the OP is really just looking to implement the two interfaces, and is stuck with the clash. It would be very strange to name a type parameter `TypeA` when one had an actual type called `TypeA` as well. (Can you imagine calling the method using `TypeB` as a type argument for a type parameter called `TypeA`? Confusing as heck.)

Comment: Yes, and the explicit interface implementation you showed nicely covers this needs without any crazy headache !